# CSS won't link to HTML, tried everything

Tags: html, css

I've tried everything! My CSS file is in my root folder, every HTML file works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Kyra Moonrae Art</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Try to look for misspelt file names.  You are linking href="style.css" and the file may have a name like stylle.css .

Comment: This is a typo. You did not close a `meta` tag. Voting to close.

Comment: Check your syntax with the W3C Markup Validation Service (https://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 1):

There is a HTML error. Just add `>` after `initial-scale=1.0"`.

Comment: While this does answer the question, please refrain from answering "typo" type questions since nobody searches "typo" - and this answer is not useful to any other visitor to the site.

Comment: Well, maybe there are other people who can't get their CSS to load and they will look for a typo in their code after reading this page. I see your point though, noted.

Comment: yes but thats what you have the comments for. Ther eeven is specifically a closign and delete flag for typo-errors.